# rails custom path on concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So here I have my routes

```
concern :search do
  scope '/search' do
    get '/', to: 'users#search'
    get '/schedule/:id', to: 'schedules#user'
  end
end

concerns :search

scope '/dashboard' do  
  concerns :search
end
```

The problem is rails didn't give me path helpers. How can I have different path for my concerns based on where I call it. I'd like to have something like this

```
search_path
search_schedule_path

dashboard_search_path
dashboard_search_schedule_path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've figured it

```
concern :search do
  scope '/search', as: :search do
    get '/', to: 'users#search'
    get '/schedule/:id', to: 'schedules#user', as: :schedule
  end
end

concerns :search

scope '/dashboard', as: :dashboard do  
  concerns :search
end
```

and here is my path helper

```
search_path
search_schedule_path

dashboard_search_path
dashboard_search_schedule_path
```